# Line break and other marking showing when I connect SharePoint discussion Board to Outlook

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

We are currently migrating our interoffice Q and A process to SharePoint 2007 Discussion board.   By connecting the SharePoint Discussion board to Outlook we can continue to use Outlook 2007 to post and reply to questions but with the flexibility of SharePoint.

The problem is that I have dragged and dropped old Outlook emails into the Discussion Board through Outlook.  When new users connect to the board through Outlook they see all the line breaks and other marking that are normally hidden, making it hard to read. (e.g "/span>" or "br>")

Does anyone know how to avoid these marking showing up?  Thanks